# How can I decrypt this script?

Tags: passwords, encryption

How can I decrypt passwords that are encrypted as follows:

```
function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)     {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else     {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}
```

Given that SALT_LENGTH is 9?

Comment: Brute-force or forget about it.

Comment: You can't get your cow back if it's already been minced meat. The same is true with hashing.

Comment: Also rand is not cryptographically secure, so using it as a salt generator is a terrible idea.

Comment: Furthermore using md5 for hashing nowadays is almost totally pointless given the wide availability of GPGPUs. Use [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/), [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), or even [scrypt](http://www.bsdcan.org/2009/schedule/attachments/87_scrypt.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an [encrypting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) function, this is [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), so it's not supposed to be decrypted at all. The only way one can is bruteforce using this algorithm and hoping that you finally get a collision, but this may take very long time.

Comment: I must check all possible words?

Comment: @digushi Yes, you have to and not only words but every possible combination of characters used in hashed string.

Comment: Yes. And as you understand it's tremendously huge amount of them

Comment: One of the properties of md5 is that given a hash, it is computationally infeasible to find a string that hashes to it. Whilst some novel research is being done into doing just that, in practice it's not feasible without specialized hardware.